# Submit HTML form which uses a javascript process with cURL

Tags: javascript, html, curl

Is there a way to submit using CURL, a HTML form which uses a javascript process ang does not have a name?

function saveChanges:

```js
function saveChanges()
{
   if((document.loginform.user.value=="" && document.loginform.pass.value=="")||
      (document.loginform.user.value=="" && document.loginform.pass.value!="") )
   {   
      alert("Login error: Please try again.");
      document.loginform.user.focus();
      return false;
   }   
   return true;
}
```

```html
<tr> <td height="24" width="92"><i><font face="Arial" color="#800000">Username</font></i></td>
<td height="24" width="300"><font face="Arial">
<input name=user size=32 maxlength=32 value='' style="width: 300; height: 24"></font></td> </tr>
<tr> <td height="24" width="92"><i><font face="Arial" color="#800000">Password</font></i></td>
<td height="24" width="300"><font face="Arial">
<input name=pass size=32 maxlength=32 type=password style="width: 300; height: 24"></font></td> </tr>
<tr> <td colspan=2 align=center height="70">
 <p style="margin-top: 5px"><font face="Arial"><input type=submit value='Login' onClick="return saveChanges()">
<input type=reset value='Clear'><br>
```

*Here is the command that I tried to use:*

```
curl --data "user=root&pass=XXX&submit=Login" http://10.62.76.4:9999/login.cgi --location
```

Answer (score 0):

The submit button doesn't have a name, so it won't be a successful control, so it won't appear in the data when the form is submitted.

```
--data "user=root&pass=XXX"
```

The JavaScript doesn't modify the data or prevent the normal form submission in any way, so it is irrelevant.